# Samsung Andriod Mobile does not detect 5GHz Wifi from Verizon Router

Tags: wi-fi

I have Verizon Fios Router that has following network

- Fios-95QSI-5G
- Fios-95QSI

My laptop detects and connect to 5GHz Wifi, but not my Android Samsung. How do I fix this?

Below are the specifics

- Samsung Galaxy J3 Prime (SM-J327T1)
- Android Version 7

Comment: I have a family member that also owns this phone, even though T-Mobile advertised it as being 5.8Ghz capable... **It isn't!** Unless it's just firmware locked, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: I have updated the questions as is is clear that the question is on the 5GHz Wifi system not 5G.

Comment: in settings of Fios Router enable 2.4GHz Wifi for more compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry to tell you..

Your phone [is not 5g.](https://www.phonemore.com/specs/samsung/galaxy-j3-prime/sm-j327t1/)

Your phone was created in 2017 before there were any 5g carriers or even 5g phones.

Network technology for this phone is limited to 2G, 3G, and 4G but **don't fret!** this is still a really nice phone and supports wifi!

Why don't you just use Wifi?  It's fast.. [faster on most ways.. slower in a few others.](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/5g-vs-wi-fi/)

Comment: Not your downvoter, but I think he is talking about the 5.8Ghz wifi band. Indicated by him mentioning his dual band verizon router.

Comment: OMG @Tim_Stewart .. I think you nailed it! :) I don't know why I didn't even think of that.  I appreciate your "setting me straight".. I am going to leave this post until it is all settled.. delete it if it is costing me points. :-) THANKS!

Comment: Lol so it was a 5th gen cellular question then?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unfortunately you will have to purchase a new phone to connect to the 5Ghz band.

Your phone only supports **802.11-b/g/n over 2.4 GHz**.

This information is from the Samsung website, under the show all specs tab for the phone.

https://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/phones/all-other-phones/galaxy-j3-prime--t-mobile--sm-j327tzkatmb/

Comment: Please know though.. 5ghz is not "BETTER".. only different.  Performance with this band varies on usage.  5ghz will not have interference from many devices to include microwaves.. but in ***my house*** 2.4ghz simply goes through more stuff like walls and carries a little farther.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas, get some beamforming action going, it has much better object penetration.

Comment: According to [Phoneandmore](https://www.phonemore.com/specs/samsung/galaxy-j3-prime/sm-j327t1/) this phone has 802.11 a/b/g/n (2.4Ghz, 5Ghz). Where did you got the information from that it is a 2.4GHz only?

Comment: @Robert. We own one, its lies. Look at other sources, you will find conflicting Information